# get the closest

Tags: sql

How do I get output in the below format using sql?
I am able to do it with case sum, but I am not able to get unique user count in the same line.

```
id   unique_users  male_count  female_count
101      3            1            2
201      1            0            1
.
.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look into SUM with CASE for the gender split?

Comment: conditional aggregation is the key concept to look up in the future but juergend presents a good answer for you on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative counts distinct males and females.

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT "USER") AS unique_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DECODE(gender,'M',"USER")) AS male_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DECODE(gender,'F',"USER")) AS female_count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

And the same but without the Oracle specific DECODE function.

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT "USER") AS unique_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN "USER" ELSE NULL END) AS male_count,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE gender WHEN 'F' THEN "USER" ELSE NULL END) AS female_count
FROM your_table
WHERE ID = 101
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

I've quoted "USER" as it has a specific meaning in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, 
       count(distinct user) as unique_users,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male_count,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female_count
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: The count of male and female won't be the unique count if I use this.